# I carn't work out how to use If statements with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a Python script that will search a page for an element with an xpath and if it doesn't find it it will look for another xpath and if it doesn't find that it will print error.

There are two possibilities of what the web page will give, one xpath or another.

However say if it does not find the first xpath then it has nothing to compare it to so it cannot see if it has found it or not!!

I need some code that will keep going if it cannot find the first xpath on the page because it might not be there!

I have tried many things from various StackExchange posts and the original documentation and it sounds like such a simple thing to do!

This is one of the pieces of code that i tried:

```
try:
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/h2')
  if elem.is_displayed():
    print ("not found")

except NoSuchElementException:
  elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/h1')
  if elem.is_displayed():
    print ("found")
```

This is another way that I tried but, they still give the same error if it cannot find the first xpath, which is "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

```
if (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/h2')).size() != 0):
print ("NOT found")

elif (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/h2')).size() != 0):
print ("Found")

else:
print ("Error")
```

I also tried this from the documentation, changed to do what I wanted:

```
try:
  element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
finally:
  ff.quit()
```

But it returned the same error even though I'm sure this is what it's meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have `try-except` in `except` block, try this

```
try:
  elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/h2')
  if elem1.is_displayed():
    print ("elem1 found and displayed")
  else:
    print ("elem1 found but not displayed")

except NoSuchElementException:
  print ("elem1 not found")
  try:
      elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/h1')
      if elem2.is_displayed():
        print ("elem2 found and displayed")
      else:
        print ("elem2 found but not displayed")
  except:
    print ("elem2 not found")
```

Comment: Thank You so much this worked amazingly!! (Minor: Line 3 should be elem1 :-), but doesn't matter)